# Access Dict with variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to create some dicts with variable names. This works perfectly with this line:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    locals()['dict{}'.format(i)] = {}
```

But how can I access on of these dictionaries?

Comment: Just don't do that. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761.

Comment: don't create names dynamically.  Use dict of dicts. Or other container type.

Comment: The same way you created them `locals()['dict1']`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was just as easy as this:

```
 i = 0
 print(locals()['dict{}'.format(i)])
```